# How to add custom fields to some user roles in the Symfony2 FOSUserBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I have a situation where I have 3 roles for the "users" of my web app - **Mentor**, **Mentee** and **Supervisor**. I have understood how to use the [FOSUserBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html) to manage users and assign roles using the `ROLE_` prefix. But there is some extra information I want to store that is specific to a particular role, like Mentors have `joindate` and `sessionscompleted`, and supervisors have `salary`. I could create 3 separate entities for each of those roles and add the extra fields wherever necessary. However when setting up the FOSUserBundle in my project's config.yml file, it has room for specifying only one entity:

```
app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb' and 'couchdb'
firewall_name: main
user_class: AppBundle\Entity\Mentor **# how do I specify the other 2 entities here?**
from_email:
    address: "%mailer_user%"
    sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately FosUserBundle does not provede that elasticity. Instead of this ypo can use

[PUGXMultiUserBundle](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle)

or simply create one class for user with optionals fields that will be null if not belongs to given role.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! I found it after googling a bit about this problem.

Comment: Actually, what do you think I should do? Have multiple user types or just one class with some fields null if inappropriate for a role?

Comment: In my opinion one class will be better for the sake of simplicity. Of course, it depends on the design, but in typical situations model of data should be as simple as possible.

Comment: I was thinking of using the EasyAdmin Bundle to manage supervisor accounts, and pugxmultiuserbundle to manage mentor and mentee accounts. I'll keep a salary field in the mentor table which will be zero for mentors who are not also supervisors

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Good luck!